# Using a CMS (Wordpress) or starting from scratch?

Tags: php, html, css, web, comparison

I am sure this topic has been discussed here before but I would like a personal feedback on whether it's worth my time and energy going the Wordpress way for this site: http://www.liturgycentrebandra.org/

It's a Catholic church based site and as you can see there sections where articles might come up regularly but it also has sections, like the Media / Books, which MIGHT need a look of their own.

I call myself a 'web developer' in quotes because I am a self taught beginner for HTML and CSS. The contact us page was created by getting a readymade PHP script and I see the gallery tab would need something like that too.

My friend told me to learn PHP since that would give me more control instead of Wordpress since they would have 'content management templates' that won't give me enough freedom to do what I want. I remember when I was new to webdesigning and I spent hours trying to figure out Dreamweaver and then ended up getting things done faster just handcoding in notepad!

So, sorry if this is a ramble but I greatly appreciate any thorough feedback on what I should do. Someone mentioned that http://online.wsj.com/public/page/magazine-index.html?mg=blogs-wsj is made in Wordpress. I think that's impressive. But would a PHP,HTML, and CSS guy have done the work faster or Wordpress guy? Also, websites like Wallbase.cc are an inspiration to me since it seems the creator just learnt all the various tricks by hanging around sites like HERE.

Comment: I believe this should be possible with Wordpress. Just choose a good theme that nearly/completely meets all your needs and then you can make edits using Child Templates (making sure you can update the Main Theme without losing your changes). Using a CMS like Wordpress is FASTER than creating your website from scratch, you also have neat plugins that you can add.

Comment: Wordpress themes are written in PHP. Wordpress is nice because it allows non-developers to write content, which is something that a custom-made PHP solution won't offer.

Comment: @Blender: but if the structure of the template is ok for his needs the looks can be changed almost completely with just css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has a CMS side to it too and is widely used in the development community.  I wouldn't strike it off the list of possibilities for any site.

In terms of what you want to do I would say it would work well but you'll need to be comfortable with editing HTML and CSS to customise the look.  Creating themes from scratch can be quite tricky so I wouldn't go that route if you're a newbie.

Drupal has an extensive library of themes that you can look through with more added daily so that could be a good option but you'll need to get to grips with PHP to get it going and it has a learning curve.  There are many books available though, see [this site](http://www.packtpub.com/books/all?keys=drupal)

Similarly Joomla has a large libraries of themes but again requires customisation.

Overall I'd go with what you're most comfortable with but using code to create something from scratch is still the most flexible option as you are creating exactly what you want and the forums and docs for each language will give you great support.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use Wordpress, check out these links to get you started;

- http://wordpress.org/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_Files
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/one-click-child-theme/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/ [Contact Form]
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=gallery [Gallery Plugins]

You also have a dedicated Wordpress stackexchange forum

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

Basically wordpress is essentially a blogging system, rather than a CMS. So for a site with articles i would rather go with a CMS like Joomla or Drupal.

Comment: It might be a blogging system, but you don't have to configure it as a blog ;) and in that case Wordpress is 'easier' to configure than Joomla or Drupal.

Comment: Did you test any version of WordPress since 1.5 or? We use it daily for all projects where a CMS is required by clients, if WordPress fit. None of these projects are blogs. One of our former client is running a HUGE news site with articles, forums, etc and it's powered by WP (and bbPress I believe). WP have templates like any good CMS, you can do whatever you want with them and Posts,Pages and CPT. But the most important thing is normal people understand the interface right on and can publish and manage things without being developers.

Comment: I shared my knowlegde with you, okay maybe my sources were unclear, but no need to get cocky. You can use lua to create 3d games, but it's not neccesary good.